# Image data not loading in async waterfall

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

After uploading image to the app, the base64 image data(basically a very long string) does not load into the variable during async call.

```
var async = require('async');
var img_data;

// ... some functions grab img_data from frontend

console.log(img_data); // works

var add_item = function(){
    console.log(img_data); // works
    async.waterfall([
        function(callback){
            console.log(img_data); // doesn't work
            setTimeout(function(){
                console.log(img_data); // works
                // do some stuff and save the image
                callback(null, 'all done');
            }, 1000);
        }
    ], function(err, result){
        // handle err/result
    });
}

// if add item btn clicked, then
add_item();
```

It seems `img_data` isn't loaded, so I guess, I need to wait. But how to decide the time required for timeout? (variation in image data size) And in the cases when no image is uploaded, there is time wastage. How to wait only until image data loaded in the variable?

Comment: What exactly is `img_data`, I'm assuming it's not just `undefined` like in the posted code

Comment: It does not make sense, you are calling `callback` outside of `setTimeout` function

Comment: @adeneo i mentioned it is base64 image data

Comment: @madox2 `callback` can be ignored, problem isnt with callback, its with image data not being available in the function

Comment: Is this a backend of frontend code? How do you get the img_data?

Comment: @dsdenes yes, actually using `ngImgCrop`, i didn't think that part of code was relevant, so i didnt include it to prevent clutter.

Comment: Sorry but I still don't get the point. Is it a code snippet runned by the browser or it's a nodejs script? What sets img_data? Will it be available later? Do you want to wait the img_data to be setted (to not be undefined)?

Comment: @dsdenes 1. its a nodejs script, 2. you can imagine a function at the moment which recieves data from frontend's `ngImgCrop` service (data sent using angular $http), 3. Exactly, that is my problem.

Comment: Ok, if it's a backend code, and the $http service called it, then the data should be immediately available after the endpoint has been called. That's what statelessness is about. What kind of web application framework are you using? Express / Koa ? It the data is available at the first step ("works"), why do you want to wait for it?